# Load table from saved cookie

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to work out how to save and load data from tables using cookies.

I have been able to save the data to the cookie, but the load function isn't working.

Any idea on how I can make this work?

Basically, I want the cookie to save the data in the table using the "save" button. Then you can mess about with the table and the "load" button will bring it back to how it looked when it was saved.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%" id="myTable">
   <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th >Col 2</th> 
    <th >Col 3</th>
    <th>Col 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true" id="left">-</td>
    <td contenteditable="true" id="left">-</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<p id = "paragraph">

</p>

<button type= "submit" class="button" onclick="addRow()">
  Add Row
</button>

<button type= "submit" class="button" onclick="addCol()">
  Add Col
</button>

<button type= "submit" class="button" onclick="saveTable()">
  Save
</button>

<button type= "submit" class="button" onclick="LoadTable()">
  Load
</button>

<script>
function addRow()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var endOfRows = table.rows.length; // length of rows
  var row = table.insertRow(endOfRows);
  var endOfCols = table.rows[0].cells.length; // end of cols

  for(var i = 0; i< endOfCols; i++)
  {
    var cell = row.insertCell(i);
        cell.innerHTML = "-";
    if( i == endOfCols-1)
    {
        cell.contentEditable = "false";
    }
    else
    {
        cell.contentEditable = "true";
    }

    if(i > 1)
    {
        cell.style.textAlign = "right";
    }
    else
    {
        cell.style.textAlign = "left";
    }
  }
}
function addCol()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var rowLength = table.rows.length;
  var endOfCol = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
        {
             var firstRow = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i];
         var cell = firstRow.insertCell(endOfCol-1);
       cell.contentEditable = "true"
       if(i == 0)
         {
        cell.innerHTML = "-";
        cell.style.textAlign = "center";
            cell.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        cell.style.color = "white";
        cell.style.fontWeight = "600";
       }
       else
       {
        cell.innerHTML = "-";
       }

        }
}

function saveTable()
{
     var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
     var noOfRows = table.rows[0].cells.length; // amount of cols
     var noOfCols = table.rows.length;
     var data = '';
     for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
     {
         for(var j = 0; j < table.rows[0].cells.length-1; j++)
        {
                data += table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML + ",";
          }
     }
   setCookie("data", data, noOfCols, noOfRows, 60);
   alert("Cookie Saved");
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, noOfRows, noOfCols, exdays) {

    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue  +";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function LoadTable()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    var rowLength = table.rows.length;
  var endOfCol = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  var data = getCookie("data");  
  var array = data.split(',');
  var count = 0;
  for(var i =1;i<rowLength;i++)
  {
    for(var j = 0; j < endOfCol-1; j++)
    {       
      table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = array[count];
      count++;
    }
  }
}

function getCookie(cname)
{
    var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) 
  {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') 
        {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) 
        {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
  }
    return "";
}
```

PS. I need to do this where the last column is adding up the numbers from the other columns on that row, so we want to skip this column when adding the data, and also not save whatever is in this cell.

Comment: are you sure you want to use a cookie, as opposed say to localStorage? cookies are actually sent along with any web request, which increases the size of the request. Also some web servers by default can have problems with large cookies. I know IIS/.NET can have this issue. If you're storing hundreds of chars, you might be better off with localStorage

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to learn with a few questions and this one wont let me use anything else.

Comment: understood. do you know how to use your web browser's developer tools? like setting breakpoints in your code, stepping through and inspecting values?

Comment: I do. But its actually knowing how to load the table that I am having problems with. I dont know a proper way to do it.

Comment: good starting point would be to set a breakpoint in your LoadTable, right after the split probably, and see if the array looks right. If it does, work forward into the loop. if it doesn't look right, then look farther back to see if it's a problem when saving the cookie or a problem in reading the cookie.